# Showing long strings in wxpython Combobox dropdown

Tags: combobox, wxpython

In a wxpython Combobox, long strings get left-truncated in the dropdown portion.  This can result in some values looking identical when they aren't. I'd like to provide better information to the user than that.

The following options occur to me:

1. Insert elipses in the middle of the string before adding it to the combobox's dropdown choices and expanding it back before placing back in the edit portion.
2. Show a tooltip of the full string when the user mouses/hovers over a value in the dropdown.

Problem is, the Combobox class does not expose events that enable either of the above.

How can I intercept the events corresponding to either of the above?  Any other ideas for making long combobox strings visible to the user?

Thanks,
RichK

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the ComboCtrl instead of the ComboBox. The benefit is that the ComboCtrl is a custom widget, so it allows more flexibility. For example, the ComboCtrl provides a scrollbar for long strings. Check out the wxPython demo for some good examples.